# Can't access GData contacts anymore

Tags: python, authorization, contacts, gdata

I always used the following code to access Google contacts:

```
import gdata.contacts.service
gd_client = gdata.contacts.service.ContactsService()
gd_client.ClientLogin('xxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx')
query = gdata.contacts.service.ContactsQuery()
query.max_results = 10000
feed = gd_client.GetContactsFeed(query.ToUri())
print feed
```

However, I am now getting the following `Login required` error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./1.py", line 10, in <module>
    feed = gd_client.GetContactsFeed(query.ToUri())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/contacts/service.py", line 103, in GetContactsFeed
    return self.Get(uri, converter=gdata.contacts.ContactsFeedFromString)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/service.py", line 1107, in Get
    'reason': server_response.reason, 'body': result_body}
gdata.service.RequestError: {'status': 401, 'body': '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">\n <error>\n  <domain>GData</domain>\n  <code>required</code>\n  <location type="header">Authorization</location>\n  <internalReason>Login Required</internalReason>\n </error>\n</errors>\n', 'reason': 'Unauthorized'}
```

What am I doing wrong? I failed to find a solution in Google, yet I found someone saying that some similar code is deprecated.

Thanks!

L.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution. I've got a similar error using this script:
http://www.baablogic.net/googlecontacts.py

It uses paython-gdata and I'm also getting a response from Google saying I'm unauthorized.

Comment: No, but it seems google changed the authorization procedure. It is kind of complicated now and poorly documented. I gave up trying.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the quick answer.